# preventDefault(); jquery child affected

Tags: jquery, html, preventdefault

I checked answer about that but couldn't adapt a solution so need your help. I'd like the `preventdefault();` works only to parents element but here it works for everything

```
<ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#"><b>Accueil</b></a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><b>Liste serveurs</b></a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#"><b>sub 1</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><b>sub 2</b></a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.links > li').on('click',function(noway) {
        noway.preventDefault();

});
```

Goal is when I click on *Liste serveurs*, **.sub appear**, but here when I click on *sub 1*, nothing happened. I'd like to go to the sub 1 link.

EDIT: I don't get it, I feel it is totally wrong, but it works.

```
$('.links > li').on('click',function(noway) {
            if($(this).attr("class") === "sub") { noway.preventDefault(); }

    });
```

Comment: That is because `.on()` listens to ALL click events bubbling up to the direct descendents `<li>` of `.links`  (also includes the ones originating from `<a>`), that's why none of the children would work. You have no clarified which element's click event you want to disable tho — is it the `<a>` element of top level links, or otherwise?

Comment: What are your trying to prevent in a `li` click if there's no default for this kind of element?

Comment: You mean it effects the link click?
What exactly are you trying to do. maybe it will be clearer....

Comment: I just edit my post. Changing on .click() does nothing. I want the sub 1 link go somewhere, now it is stop by preventdelfault();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the most basic way....why making it complex!!

```
$('ul.links > li > a').click(function(event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ge7kgL76/)

**Meaning :**

`preventDefault()` only for direct descendant `a` of `li` and this `li` should be direct descendant of `ul.links`

Comment: Ah, sorry it prevent all links in the menu to load, Accueil too.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
<ul class="links">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com"><b>Accueil</b></a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><b>Liste serveurs</b></a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a rel="1" href="http://www.google.com"><b>sub 1</b></a></li>
                        <li><a rel="1" href="#"><b>sub 2</b></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(noway) {
                if($(this).attr("rel")!="1")
                noway.preventDefault();
    })
 });
```

Comment: You have a missing `);` to close your handler.